# How do I make Python site packages available outside of my install directory?

Tags: python, windows, libraries

I'm running windows 7 and have installed Python 2.7.3. My install directory is C:\Python27 and the packages I've downloaded (e.g numpy, pyserial, scipy, etc.) can be found in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.

Is it possible to install a library (in particular pyserial) to a network drive? Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is for anyone with Python installed on their machine to be able to run something, even if they haven't installed a particular library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sys.path.append](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) is what you are looking for.